# Replace parenthesis with another character only if they contain a word

Tags: php, regex

Input example:

```
This, (  will not be replaced   ) , 
but (this will) and also (this) will be replaced, 
also ((this)) and () ()() (()). 
If possible, also ())).
Multiline (will not
be replaced).
```

Output example:

```
This, (  will not be replaced   ) , 
but [this will] and also [this] will be replaced, 
also [[this]] and [] [][] [[]].
If possible, also []]].
Multiline (will not
be replaced).
```

As you can see, I want to replace the parenthesis character with another type of parenthesis, only if they contain a word with no extra whitespaces.

The replace should happen only in the same line, so if open ( is in line 1 and closing ) is in another line, no need for replacement.

Is this possible?

A poor attempt:

```
preg_replace('/\([a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '[', $s);
preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)/', ']', $s);
```

Comment: Downvoters are welcomed to say what they don't like about the question, so I can learn.

Comment: Good question but no efforts.

Comment: Well, I have no idea how to do it, or where to start it from...

Comment: I don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: So you don't have any idea about coding things?

Comment: Well, regex !== coding. Also by this point, if someone as smart as you knew if what I asked is possible or not, would have answered already.

Comment: and community doesn't ask you to post a solution you don't know. It asks for your attempts otherwise you get downvotes and close votes (which you got already) since you seek a ready-to-go answer.

Comment: and to answer your question: yes, it's possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace those that has word in them then why did you replace empty brackets too? I solved it with recursion in regex and preg_replace_callback:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\((?!\s)([^()\r\n]*|(?R))*\)/', 
    function($matches) {
        # $matches is an array that includes all strings matches by regex
        return str_replace(['(', ')'], ['[', ']'], $matches[0]);
    }, $text);`
```

$text is your input text.

Produced output is as follows:

> This, (  will not be replaced   ) ,  but [this will] and also [this]
>   will be replaced,  also [[this]] and [] [][] [[]].  If possible, also
>   [])). Multiline (will not be replaced).

Comment: I would never be able to reach this solution by myself. Thanks a lot.